# Position div element on top of image even when window is resized

Tags: html, css, position

I want the red box to cover the black box at all times, even when window is resized. The size of the box is 40px*40px and does not change in size when the window is resized. All the content changes in size except the black box. Also the distance from the top stays the same. How can I achive this so that the red box is always on top.

[image]

Comment: use 2 divs and add `z-index` to red div. something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/kLaox5cr/8/

Answer (score 0):

just create a div element which includes both

Comment: I do not have any control over the black box whatsoever. I know it sounds strange but I really can just move the red one.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using the same properties for the black and red(so that if you resize, they fall at the same place) and use the z-index to make sure that the red is on top.

Comment: The grey page is an iframe from another page. It is a pdf. And there is a button I want to cover which is the black box.